# Mockito thenReturn method not found

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm pretty new to Mokito, so hopefully this is a simple question.  I've been looking at all sorts of examples online, but I can only seem to be able to build thenReturn calls that return Booleans.  I'm pretty stumped.

Here's my code:

```
@Test
public void addSubscriptionShouldSubscribeForIsaData() throws SubscriptionException {
    ParrotSubscription mockSub = mock(ParrotSubscription.class);
    when(parrotPrimaryComponent.addSubscription(Mockito.any(ParrotSubscription.class))).thenReturn(mockSub);

    ParrotSubscription parrotSubscription = isaComponent.addSubscription(subscription);
    assertThat(parrotSubscription).isNotNull();
```

Seems straightforward enough, but when I compile I get:

```
/home/sleepylight/workspace/asynchrony/sensors/sensor-isa/src/test/java/com/asynchrony/mfk/sensor/isa/IsaComponentTest.java:111: error: no suitable method found for thenReturn(ParrotSubscription)
    when(parrotPrimaryComponent.addSubscription(Mockito.any(ParrotSubscription.class))).thenReturn(mockSub);
                                                                                       ^
method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(Boolean) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; ParrotSubscription cannot be converted to Boolean)
method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(Boolean,Boolean...) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; ParrotSubscription cannot be converted to Boolean)
```

So, obviously that's not right.

The method I'm testing is quite simple.

```
public ParrotSubscription addSubscription(String subscriptionText) throws SubscriptionException {
    try {
        return primaryComponent.addSubscription(subscriptionText);

    } catch (DataQueryParserException e) {
        throw new SubscriptionException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause(), e.getLineNumber(), e.getStartIndex(),
                e.getStopIndex());
    }
}
```

It's just a wrapper around the addSubscription method of primaryComponent, which is what I'm trying to mock.

Is there perhaps an include I missed, or some function signature I need to define?  I checked out the method min Mokito.java and it looks like it's just supposed to take an generic type.  I'm using **mokito-core-2.18.3** if that helps.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Could you provide signature of `addSubscription` method?

Comment: Sure!  The method I'm mocking looks like this:     public ParrotSubscription addSubscription(ParrotSubscription parrotSubscription)

Comment: I don't have anything else defined for mock-wise defined for this function.  Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: `parrotPrimaryComponent` is a mock object right? I'm not getting why you are mocking that method and at the same time invoking it in the next step. Would help if you add the class method body as well

Comment: isaComponent is contains a parrotComponent.  The isaComponent really just wraps the parrotComponent call, when then should return a new parrotSubscription.  You are correct, parrotComponent is a mock, and I'd like it to return either a mock of a subsciption object (preferred) or a new subscription object when it's called.  The test is really just to verify the pass-through works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  It was a silly typo.  I was passing ParrotSubscription.class to addSubscription, which does actually return a boolean.  The version that takes a String returns a new ParrotSubscription.  I had refactored a lot of this code the other day and just missed it.

So, lesson learned.  The return type is tied directly to the function being mocked, and I need to be sure I'm calling the right method.  Thank you for your help.  Turns out this was just a simple mistake.